# Flink : How to real time monitor a job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How could we monitor a flink job in real time. For example if the job fails some alert is generated. Is there any external library present or something already available in flink. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is covered nicely in this blog post: [Monitoring Apache Flink Applications 101](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/02/25/monitoring-best-practices.html).

The usual approach is to connect Flink to the metrics and monitoring platform of your choice -- Flink supports quite a few. You'll want to choose a metrics reporter from the list [in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/).